# How to search for a phrase with quotes in Lucene

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, kibana

I have to search for documents in which a given field's value has this:
`"ns":100`
I used the following Lucene query but it doesn't return me any output:
`(json.req.variables: "\"ns\":100")`

The value in the said field is something like this:
json.req.variables:

```
   "variables":{
      "anotherField":{
         "againAnotherField":[
            {
               "a":{
                  "ns":100
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

What would be the correct Lucene query to get the desired results?

Comment: The colon (`:`) is also a special character, assuming you are using the Lucene [classic query parser](https://lucene.apache.org/core/8_11_0/queryparser/org/apache/lucene/queryparser/classic/package-summary.html#Escaping_Special_Characters), under the covers. Try `"\"ns\"\:100"` instead.

Comment: @andrewJames This didn't work either.

Comment: Understood. This approach works in pure Lucene, when the data is indexed using Lucene's Standard Analyzer. Sorry, I am not familiar with how this translates to Kibana syntax. Small suggestion: Perhaps if you add the `elasticsearch` tag to the question, you may reach a wider community, if you don't get an answer.